# use boost::thread to run a functor but destructor is wrongly called

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, destructor

I use boost::thread to run a functor. I suppose to see the destructor of object *a* be called twice in the main thread. However, **sometimes**, I find out the destructor is called once in main thread and once in the thread invoked. The class A does some complicated stuff thus this phenomenon does not always happen. Anyone has idea how this could happen?

```
int main()
{
    A a; // A is a functor
    boost::thread myThread(a);
    while (true)
    {
        // sleep every second until interruption caught
    }
    myThread.interrupt();
    myThread.join();
}
```

By the way, I use boost::thread myThread(boost::ref(a)) now and everything seems to work well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::thread` copies the arguments and passes the copies to your thread function, or to `operator()` of your function object.

If you need to pass a reference, use `boost::ref` as you do now.